# autoexpect fails to run

Tags: expect

I just installed the expect package (which is supposed to contain autoexpect).
When I run `autoexpect`, I get this error:

```
can't find package Expect
    while executing
"package require Expect"
    (file "/usr/bin/autoexpect" line 6)
```

Has anyone experienced else this problem? Were you able to get in running?

Comment: Package `expect` according to this page: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-arm64/expect_5.45.4-2build1_arm64.deb.html depends on `tcl-expect` which provides the missing module. Maybe somehow you installed `expect` without its dependencies?

Comment: ... or the dependencies were already installed, but broken perhaps?

Comment: @raj nah I had tcl-expect installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Anaconda you can use this command:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin autoexpect ./shell.sh
```

This is because of conflict between Anaconda and expect.

more details in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341867/cant-find-package-expect-while-executing-package-require-expect).