# Can't find package Expect while executing "package require Expect"

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, expect

I want to use autoexpect for a simple .sh file but the terminal shows this error:

```
can't find package Expect
    while executing
"package require Expect"
    (file "/usr/bin/autoexpect" line 6)
```

my terminal command is:

```
autoexpect shell.sh
```

I remove expect and install it again but no difference with past!

Can anyone help me?

[image: already newest version]

This is output of `dpkg -l | grep tcl; which tclsh; which tclsh8.6; dpkg -S Expect; echo $PATH`. Does Anaconda contradict expect?

[image: installed, anaconda path]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to install the main Expect [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fexpect) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install expect
```

and it will install `tcl-expect` as dependency for you.

To run Expect scripts avoiding problems with Anaconda you have to manually specify PATH variable and then run your expect/tcl script:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
autoexpect ./shell.sh
```

or in one line:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin autoexpect ./shell.sh
```

To ease every autoexpect command execution you can add the following alias to the `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias autoexpect='PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin autoexpect'
```

Comment: Thanks. It works :)))).  I should edit this path every time I use expect? @N

Comment: You can try to setup `alias autoexpect='PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin autoexpect'` in your `~/.bashrc` .

Comment: Thanks. @N0rbert

Answer (score 0):

When using conda, conda's own expect overrides the original expect command, creating a conflict.

Solution:

Reinstall the expect command

```
conda install -c eumetsat expect
```

When using unbuffer again, it is back to normal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).